# Issues with formtastic and client side validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, formtastic, client-side-validation

Got an error

```
uninitialized constant Formtastic::FormBuilder(NameError)
```

And this, in my config/initializers/client_side_validations.rb

```
require 'client_side_validations/formtastic' if defined?(::Firntastic)
#seems like comment this line out will fix the problem
#but I need Formtastic here
```

Did some research and found out this issue may probably caused by the version of client_side_validation.

Here by, I provied the version of the gem

```
formstastic(1.2.4)
client_side_validations(3.1.0)
```

If you know anything about this, anything, do tell me.

Comment: well, I use client_side_validations 3.0.5 instead of 3.1.0 and seems problem sloved

Answer (score 1):

Looks to my eyes like a couple of typos: "Firntastic" and "formstastic". You've probably solved this already, but if not, give those a look.